# Debug point in Eclipse going in .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In Eclipse have an Ant project A. For this project in the lib folder by adding a jar, added a dependency of other Java Project B. When I add debug breakpoint in the Java project B, it goes in the .class file instead of .java file. 
Also in the .class file during debug if we try to see the details at break point it gives following
**Cannot make a static reference to non static field**
In the debug view added the source folder of the Project B but still facing same issue. How can this be resolved

Answer (score 1):

As you have added a jar file. That means the project has reference to only the jar file which contains only the pre-compiled class and not the actual source codes.

To have the access to the source codes, add a dependency using the other project as a library project in eclipse.

This way while debugging you will have access to the actual source code.

Make sure you remove the jar file before doing this and also do a clean rebuild to avoid and redundant references.

Comment: just did that but now the debug point goes to the .java file. but on trying to see the values get -----------------------------------------------------------------  Unable to evaluate the selected expression. To perform evaluation an expression must be compiled in context of a java projects build path.  The current execution is not context is not associated with java project in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

When eclipse opens the break point on the .class file you need to locate the jar file and then map the sources of the jar. By doing so it does not matter to where the breakpoont is mapped. Eclipse will then open the relevant sources.